# Is it possible to migrate a Windows installation to another machine or Parallels?

Tags: windows-7, windows, virtual-machine, parallels

I've got a Windows 7 machine that's about to die and I want to transfer my data to another machine, or possibly to a disk image that I would then run inside of Parallels on my Mac.  I could of course install Windows 7 from scratch, but then I'd have to reinstall dozens of programs and transfer many gigabytes of data, all of which takes a huge amount of time.  So I'm wondering if it's possible to make an image of my Windows installation and just ghost it onto another machine, or into a new virtual machine in Parallels.  Can this be done?

Comment: You may need to reactivate it because it will see Parallels as different hardware, and Windows keys are tied to the motherboard. If you have Windows 7 retail, that will be no problem, but you cannot re-license OEM versions without paying full price for another key. http://tinyurl.com/ca97z47

Comment: Be aware that some software is device-specific and will not work if it is simply copied from one machine to another. Watch out for applications that require specific drivers or come packaged with hardware.

Comment: Both of these comments convinced me that my idea isn't worth doing, since it would still cost a chunk of cash to get new software, and it sounds like a huge hassle too.  If someone reposts as an answer, I would accept it as answering my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answers and comments made me decide that this approach is far too messy and I just opted to reinstall everything from scratch.  Thanks to all contributors for their input.

Answer (score 1):

- You can use [Acronis True Image 2013](http://www.acronis.com/homecomputing/products/trueimage/index.html) (30 days free trial) to create a full backup of your PC.
  With the same software you restore that backup on other machines.
  Of course you have to re-install drivers when your hardware has changed.
- [This article](http://kb.parallels.com/en/5728) states that Parallels can import Acronis Backups.
  (Since I don't own a Mac I can't tell you how well both software act together)